# Cannot get Dnsmasq to work in Sierra (for local development)

Tags: osx, dnsmasq, development, resolv.conf

so despite my numerous attempts at getting Dnsmasq to work, I'm posting here to get some help from the community. Summary: I'm trying to get all `.local` domains to automatically resolve to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

This is a fresh/clean installation of Sierra on a 2014 MBP 15. I already have Homebrew, Composer, Node, etc installed. Here are the steps I have taken so far following guides from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287851/cannot-get-dnsmasq-to-work-in-sierra-for-local-development) and [here](https://medium.com/@narakuw/brew-install-dnsmasq-in-macos-sierra-26021c824be8):

1. `brew install dnsmasq`
2. `/usr/local/etc` already existed when brew was installed, so I `nano /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`
3. Inside this I have:

   `address=/local/127.0.0.1
   no-resolv
   strict-order`
4. `sudo brew services start dnsmasq`
5. `sudo mkdir /etc/resolver`
6. `sudo nano /etc/resolver/local` --> `nameserver 127.0.0.1`
7. I finally restarted my Mac.

---

Once restarted I opened my zsh terminal, and tried to both ping and dig `test.local` :

`ping -c 2 test.local` --> *ping: cannot resolve test.local: Unknown host*

`dig test.local @127.0.0.1` --> *connection timed out; no servers could be reached*

---

I've tried adding `127.0.0.1` manually to the top of my DNS Servers under Network Preferences. In `dnsmasq.conf`, I've also tried `address=/.local/127.0.0.1` (notice '.' in front of 'local' being the difference). Finally I've tried restarting dnsmasq: `brew services restart dnsmasq` ... unfortunately, none of these helped.

Is there a step I missed or misconfigured?

Comment: Please do not keep both questions open, as cross posting is not allowed per our FAQ.

Comment: Apologies, I'll close the other one

Answer (score 3):

```
brew services restart dnsmasq
```

This command will run with your current user, thus dnsmasq doesn't have the permission to listen on port `53`

I suggest to stop that process first

```
brew services stop dnsmasq
```

And then restart dnsmasq with root user

```
sudo brew services restart dnsmasq
```

Check service status

> sudo brew services list

```
Name           Status  User Plist
dnsmasq        started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
```

Make sure the `User` is `root`

Comment: NOTE: The brew commands use the word `services`, not `service`. I tried to edit this answer, but I didn't have enough characters edited to get over SO's threshold.

Comment: thanks @rinogo, edited

Comment: Thank you for this, I always forget the sudo and it seems to work without needing sudo, until I then try and ping from the terminal!

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue using OSX High Sierra where dnsmasq wasn't working for me. I also noticed this:

```
$ dnsmasq

dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 169.254.51.195: 
Permission denied
```

So I tried `sudo dnsmasq` and now all of a sudden, my local domains are working. I have no idea why.

Comment: `dnsmasq: command not found`

Comment: When dnsmasq installed via brew, it runs as a service. If you need to run as a command you need to have `/usr/local/sbin` in your `$PATH`, since that's where it's located.